# Does Plus 44 require your answer to be the first?

Tags: bug, status-completed, winter-bash, time, winter-bash-2021

[Plus 44](https://winterbash2021.stackexchange.com/plus-44)'s description says, in order to earn it, you have to

> Answer a question of score four or greater with an answer of score four or greater.

As far as I can tell, [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/238589) answer should qualify me for this hat on [Code Golf.SE](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) (the question was posted ~3 hours after Winter Bash started). However, I currently [don't have the hat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/66833/caird-coinheringaahing#winter-bash).

[Catija hypothesised](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59913247#59913247) that the hat can only be awarded if the answer is the first one (whether to reach 4 upvotes, or first to post, is unknown), which would fit with the fact that [another user](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95126/dominic-van-essen?tab=topactivity#winter-bash) has this hat, as they had the [first answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/238575/generate-the-chess-numbers?answertab=oldest#tab-top).

Is this a hidden part of the trigger, or is this a bug, and all answers should receive the hat?

Comment: It's unclear which description was intended, but in the code comment the description of the hat is: "Answer an unanswered +4 question with a +4 answer" and being the first answer is a requirement in the query.

Comment: @animuson So are you guys planning to fix the description or the query?

Comment: For public hats, the query should follow the description.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The criteria for awarding does indeed require that your answer is the first answer for the question (including other answers that were deleted).

The hat description has been updated to:

[image: Answer a previously unanswered question of score four or greater with an answer of score four or greater.]

> Answer a previously unanswered question of score four or greater with an answer of score four or greater.